# Sum of deviations from mean and Mean deviation around mean

Tags: statistics, means

We know, Sum of deviation of variate from their A.M. is always zero that is $\sum(x_i- \mu)$ where $x_i$ are all the elements and $\mu$ is the arithmetic mean.

Also mean deviation is the mean of the variates around a given quantity. If it is asked to find the mean deviation around the mean, then it should be zero, right? This is where I am unable to understand it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{mean})=0$ then $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{mean})=0$. But I don't know if this is your definition of "mean deviation," since that sometimes refers to $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - x_{mean}|$ instead.

Comment: @angryavian The mean deviation is defined as a statistical measure that is used to calculate the average deviation from the mean value of the given data set. (Source: Wikipedia)
This what I mean when I say mean deviation

Comment: @ExtroMechanic Suppose you have the $3$ values $1,2,3$, then the mean is $2$, the sum of deviations is $-1+0+1=0$ but the mean deviation is $\left(|-1|+0+|1|\right)/3=2/3$.

Comment: @dxiv Yes! now I get it, the mod was the difference between them. Thank you.

Comment: If you are talking about the ["mean absolute deviation about the mean"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation#Mean_absolute_deviation_around_the_mean) then it is worth having those extra words